# CentOS 6 .sln xbuild compilation error (SteamBot)

Tags: linux, mono, centos6, xbuild, sln-file

I recently just started using linux and I'm not very familiar with some of the errors or commands.

I keep getting the following error and really can't understand why

"/home/steambotv1.0/SteamBot-master/.nuget/../.ci/exec-with-retry.sh: No such file or directory"

Why is it looking for that file? it never did on windows (it compiles fine on windows)

Can any please point me in the right direction?

Here is the rest of the error message:

XBuild Engine Version 3.0.0.0
Mono, Version 3.0.0.0
Copyright (C) Marek Sieradzki 2005-2008, Novell 2008-2011.

Build started 8/5/2015 12:00:36 AM.

---

Project "/home/steambotv1.0/SteamBot-master/SteamBot.sln" (default target(s)):
        Target ValidateSolutionConfiguration:
                Building solution configuration "Debug|Any CPU".
        Target Build:
                Project "/home/steambotv1.0/SteamBot-master/SteamTrade/SteamTrade.csproj" (default target(s)):
                        Target RestorePackages:
                                Executing: bash "/home/steambotv1.0/SteamBot-master/.nuget/../.ci/exec-with-retry.sh" mono --runtime=v4.0.30319 /home/steambotv1.0/SteamBot-master/.nuget/NuGet.exe install "packages.config" -source ""  -RequireConsent -solutionDir "/home/steambotv1.0/SteamBot-master/"
                                bash: /home/steambotv1.0/SteamBot-master/.nuget/../.ci/exec-with-retry.sh: No such file or directory
/home/steambotv1.0/SteamBot-master/.nuget/NuGet.targets: error : Command 'bash "/home/steambotv1.0/SteamBot-master/.nuget/../.ci/exec-with-retry.sh" mono --runtime=v4.0.30319 /home/steambotv1.0/SteamBot-master/.nuget/NuGet.exe install "packages.config" -source ""  -RequireConsent -solutionDir "/home/steambotv1.0/SteamBot-master/"' exited with code: 127.
                        Task "Exec" execution -- FAILED
                        Done building target "RestorePackages" in project "/home/steambotv1.0/SteamBot-master/SteamTrade/SteamTrade.csproj".-- FAILED
                Done building project "/home/steambotv1.0/SteamBot-master/SteamTrade/SteamTrade.csproj".-- FAILED
        Task "MSBuild" execution -- FAILED
        Done building target "Build" in project "/home/steambotv1.0/SteamBot-master/SteamBot.sln".-- FAILED
Done building project "/home/steambotv1.0/SteamBot-master/SteamBot.sln".-- FAILED

Build FAILED.
Errors:

/home/steambotv1.0/SteamBot-master/SteamBot.sln (default targets) ->
(Build target) ->
/home/steambotv1.0/SteamBot-master/SteamTrade/SteamTrade.csproj (default targets) ->
/home/steambotv1.0/SteamBot-master/.nuget/NuGet.targets (RestorePackages target) ->

/home/steambotv1.0/SteamBot-master/.nuget/NuGet.targets: error : Command 'bash "/home/steambotv1.0/SteamBot-master/.nuget/../.ci/exec-with-retry.sh" mono --runtime=v4.0.30319 /home/steambotv1.0/SteamBot-master/.nuget/NuGet.exe install "packages.config" -source ""  -RequireConsent -solutionDir "/home/steambotv1.0/SteamBot-master/"' exited with code: 127.

Answer (score 0):

Test if you can see the file in a terminal window opened with the same user.
If not, change the permissions in Admin mode.

Comment: This occured on a CentOS 6 VPS, the user was root, which already has all admin permissions

Comment: Check also if the "exec-with-retry.sh" file has execute permission.

Comment: "/home/steambotv1.0/SteamBot-master/.nuget/../.ci/exec-with-retry.sh" this file doesnt even exist, there's no folder in .nuget. This path/file was never required when I compiled on windows. I'm not even sure what the full path is, what is "/../"? where can i find the full path in my c# project? sorry if these are entry-level questions? I've never used linux before and I am just lost.

Comment: .sh are Linux Batch files (equivalent of Windows .bat). The missing .sh file is specific to the "SteamBot" application.  I can't help you on that matter. You will have to search solutions focusing on installation of SteamBot on Linux systems.